# The type OracleLobHandler is deprecated for spring 4.3.3

Tags: java, spring

> We are facing some issues when upgrading from **spring 3.2.2** release
>   to **4.3.3** .

The warning is as follows.

> The type OracleLobHandler is deprecated & default constructor for 
>   OracleLobHandler() is also deprecated.Any other alternative classes we
>   can use .I googled it and found something like DefaultLobHandler which
>   I am not sure .Can any one  please confirm the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 4):

You should use `DefaultLobHandler`. Following lines are from `OracleLobHandler` API documentation.

> Deprecated 
>   in favor of DefaultLobHandler for the Oracle 10g driver and higher. Consider using the 10g/11g driver even against an Oracle 9i database!
>
> DefaultLobHandler.setCreateTemporaryLob(boolean) is the direct
>   equivalent of this OracleLobHandler's implementation strategy, just
>   using standard JDBC 4.0 API. That said, in most cases, regular
>   DefaultLobHandler setup will work fine as well.

Please refer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: So just to clarify: should i set `createTemporaryLob` to `true`?